# How to add datetimefield to Django and migrate

Tags: python, django

I've added the datetimefield to my models in Django 1.8.3, and now I need to migrate. I'm trying to figure out how to add a default date but can't find any helpful information in the documentation.

I run:

```
python manage.py makemigrations demo-model
python manage.py migrate demo-model
```

And the prompt responds:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'date_uploaded' to demo-model without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
 Select an option: 1
 Please enter the default value now, as valid Python
 The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so you can do e.g. timezone.now()
```

I tried:

```
>>> 2014-08-01
```

Django says:

```
Invalid input: invalid token (<string>, line 1)
```

So I try:

```
>>> datetime(2014, 08, 01).isoformat(' ')
```

And I get the same error.

I don't know what Django wants out of me... This is undoubtedly very simple, but I can't find an example or proper documentation anywhere.

**SOLVED**
The problem is with how I was using datetime. Because the zero in '08' is being interpreted as an octal literal, it was throwing an error that wasn't being displayed.

The solution is:

```
datetime.date(2014, 8, 1)
```

Comment: you can make the field nullable, then it doesnot ask for default anymore

Comment: yeah, that would definitely be the easy fix and that's how I've dealt with it in the past, but I'd love to know how to fix it without nulling the field in the models cause I've run into this issue with other migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with:

```
datetime(2014, 8, 1)
```

Comment: Figured it out and you're close, the leading zero in the 08 was interpreted as an octal literal and throwing an error that I wasn't catching. Edit your answer and I'll give you credit: datetime.date(2014, 8, 1) :)

Answer (score 0):

Why did you call isoformat on the datetime? You need a datetime, not a string. Just do `datetime(2014, 08, 01)`.